# managed paypal accounts with least friction?

Tags: python, paypal, oauth, payment

I'd like to be able to pay the users of my site using PayPal Mass Payment. I think this is pretty straightforward if they have a PayPal account.

However, if they do not have a PayPal account, is there any way to have them sign up through my site, without leaving? Or just with a nice redirect? Whatever is least friction. I just don't want to lose users in the onboarding experience.

This is analogous to Stripe managed accounts, but I'm not sure if PayPal has such an analogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal doesn't have a way for people to sign up entirely through your site, although there are some ways to facilitate the process. You'd probably have to call PayPal to get access to some of those as they are aimed primarily at larger businesses.

However, don't neglect the easy/automatic assistance that PayPal gives you: you can pay to any email account, and if that email is not already active on a PayPal account then the payment will be waiting for them when they activate that email into an existing or new PayPal account. So you can onboard merchants to your site and leave the PayPal signup for later, when money will be waiting for them to claim. Psychologically, walking away from money is harder than than deciding not to start processing :).

Comment: I didn't know that...super valuable insight! Thanks a ton!

Comment: How long will it wait for them? If I send a payment to an email, does it stay there indefinitely? (couldn't find this online)

Comment: I think it's 30 days, after which the payment will be automatically reversed. Not sure exactly, though. Read the Mass Pay docs to get a firm answer on how exceptions with individual payouts are managed.

Answer (score 2):

[Adaptive Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/) will allow you to tie PayPal account creation into an app much like the Express Checkout flow.

To create a new account for a new user you would make a call to CreateAccount to set up the flow with PayPal.  With the response to that you'll get a token that you append to the redirect URL you send the user to at PayPal.  There, they will complete the process of actually creating their account, setting a password, etc. and will then be returned to the redirect URL you specify in the CreateAccount request.

After that you can also use AddBankAccount, AddPaymentCard, and a few other calls to fine-tune things.  The Adaptive Accounts calls are all defined here:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/#aa

Comment: Can you be more specific how that would work? I read these docs but getting a clear, concise couple sentence remark about the flow back and forth from my site/the protocol wasn't something I found anywhere...

Comment: a reference to a good implementation or code example would be amazing too

Comment: I updated the answer with some more detail.  I only have code samples in PHP.